# Directories in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I've been designing the web pages and I use to save all the contents in same folder... like index.html and css file in same directory for easy accessing... so if there are images in "img" folder then both html and css can access them like "img/img.jpg" etc....

But i came to see many webpages on the net which have specific directories assigned to all files ... like for css file it usually comes "src/css/file.css" and for javascript files "src/js/file.js"..

now the problem is if there are images in directory "img/..." which a css file (stored in separate folder in main directory "src/css/file.css") going to use  then how can i put the exact address to the location of the image into css file..

what i saw in online source codes is that css files can access them from main folder/img/img.jpg while they are in main folder/src/css/file.css .....

but when i came to do this, my images won't load and show up..

Please help me in this regard..

[image: Pictorial description]

Comment: You can go up a folder using ../, For example from src/css/file.css you can use ../img/img.png

Comment: Show examples. We aren't going to guess why you can't get paths right

Comment: @charlietfl sir! how i'm supposed to show example here? while it's whole document? or let me create a picture to demostrate the situation well...?

Comment: @HassanZia you can use `../../images/img.jpg` in the css file.

Comment: @HassanZia - Please do not edit your question to ask for different things, instead ask new questions. At the moment, the answers to not match the current question. Other developers could find your question, but do not get the answer they are looking for, and the answers could get downvoted because of edited questions.

Comment: there is limit in asking questions -_-

Comment: @HassanZia: That is still not an excuse for re-using this question to ask another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create links between your files from HTML or CSS, you need to add relative links to the files.

Take this file structure for example:

```
index.html
about.html
css/styles.css
img/bg.png
img/logo.png
```

The two HTML files are in the same directory, so linking between them is easy:

`<a href="about.html>About</a>`
`<a href="index.html>Home</a>`

However, if you want to link to the image, you would need to include the directory: `<img src=img/logo.png">`.

The CSS file is in a sub directory, so you need to link to the directory above your current location. You can do this using `../` in your file path. For example:

```
body {
    background-image: url(../img/bg.png);
}
```

Provided you keep your CSS, images and JavaScript in logical places (`css/`, `img/`, `js/`) then you should be able to store your assets in separate directories, away from your HTML files.

Comment: thanks for your kind help sir! 
should i use "dots" " .. " before the slash or they just indicating something else? and what if the file structure is like below?

about.html
src/css/styles.css
img/bg.png

now how can i access bg.png through styles.css?

Comment: You just need to visual the filesystem you're working with. If you need to go down/into a directory, you can do `src/css/styles.css` to go down two directory levels. If you need to go back up the directories, you can use `../../index.html` to return. For the code example in your comments, your `src/css/styles.css` should use `background-image: url(../../img/bg.png)` to reference the file.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you will need to go two directories up.
So, it would be:
../../images/img.jpg

Answer (score -2):

It can be acheived in php using base url to get the directory `locations/img/image.png` like so

for example it can be done like this

`<?php base_url();?>/images/img.png`

Comment: you mention base url...example doesn't show it though...not much help to anyone there when example is wrong. And how does this help in a css file?